# auto run python result in "EOF when reading a line "

Tags: python, vim

I have add the line into my *.vimrc*

```
map <F4> :w !python<cr>
```

When I open gvim to edit an unname Python file, there are only two lines in it

```
x=input("which one do you like ? ")
print(x)
```

I press <kbd>F4</kbd>, and get `EOF when  reading a line`, how to solve it?

When you add `map <F4> :w<cr>:!python %<cr>` or `imap <F4> <Esc>:w <cr>:!python %<cr>`, it can only make a named file run, if it is a no named file, the map will not work, how can I make the no named file run?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@benjifisher's answer is correct. The input (function) is the problem.

The `:w !python` pipes the program to python through stdin (Basically the same as

```
echo 'input("x")' | python
```

which also fails if run in the shell). However `input()` tries to read from stdin which it can't do because python read the program from stdin and stdin is still trying to read from the pipe. However the pipe is already at the end and won't ever contain new data. So `input()` just reads EOF.

To see that python is reading from stdin we look at `:h :w_c` which shows that the file is being passed to stdin of the cmd which in this case is python.

```
                                                        :w_c :write_c
:[range]w[rite] [++opt] !{cmd}
                        Execute {cmd} with [range] lines as standard input
                        (note the space in front of the '!').  {cmd} is
                        executed like with ":!{cmd}", any '!' is replaced with
                        the previous command :!.
```

If the buffer had contained something that wasn't reading from stdin your mapping would have worked.

For example if the unnamed buffer contains

```
print(42)
```

running the command `:w !python` in vim prints 42.

So the problem isn't that the mapping fails. The problem is that your program doesn't know how to get input. The solution is use either a named file or don't write interactive programs in vim. Use the python interpreter for that.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have `:w` in your mapping, I am assuming you either want to run the script directly from the insert mode or you want to save it anyways before running it.

Multiple commands in vim require a separator like `<bar>` i.e. (`|`) or use `<CR>` (Carriage Return) between and after commands.

You can put both of the mappings below in your `.vimrc` and they should meet your requirement on hitting `F4`, whether you are in normal mode or insert mode.

If you are in normal mode, you are fine with `map`:

```
map <F4> :w<cr>:!python %<cr>
```

While for insert mode, you would need `imap` and an `Esc` to get out of insert mode:

```
imap <F4> <Esc>:w <cr>:!python %<cr>
```

Comment: why `imap <F4> <Esc>:w <cr>:!python %<cr>` can  not work in my system?is there some other thing left?i got `no file name'.

Comment: I've tested them and they both work fine. What are you trying to do, can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: if you have named a file ,then press F4 can make you run the python file,if you have not named a file ,press F4 can make you get “no file name' .

Comment: @it_is_a_literature - You can't execute a file if that file doesn't exist. Though you can do something like this `map <F4> :w myScript.py<cr>:!python %<cr>` to save as a file and then execute it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is the `input()` line.  Python is looking for input and not finding any.  All it finds (wherever it looks) is an EOF.

Comment: This is basically correct. Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22494767/1890567). `input()` is reading from stdin but python read the program from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this without a temp file, would be to do something like this(with a small helper function):

```
function! GetContentsForPython()
    let contents = join(getline(1,'$'), "\n")
    let res = ''
    for l in split(contents, '\n')
        if len(l)
            let res = res . l . ';' 
        endif
    endfor
    let res = '"' . escape(res, '"') . '"'
    return res
endfunction

noremap <f4> :!python -c <c-r>=GetContentsForPython()<cr><cr>
```

This gets the contents of the current buffer, and replaces the newlines with semi colons so you can execute it with

```
python -c "print 'hello'"
```

There may be better ways accomplishing this, but this seems to work for me.